# How to create duplicate Product programmatically in magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1, products, duplicate

I want to duplicate product using product id programmatically. I have checked it but not found any useful solution for it.

Basically, in product details page one button near by **"Add to cart"** button and when I click it then current product duplicate in store. If product is configure that selected attributes associate product duplicate.

I got **associate product Id** when I click on button. Also I create simple product using Product id But problem is i can't Add some static attribute. I got only **selected attributes value.**

I want to clone product of selected associate product. Also after clone **I want to change quantity as well as sku.**

How to do it?

Comment: you got any solution?

Comment: Yes, but with custom code. Everything is working it. But now facing a problem with the custom option.

Comment: can you share your code please so I can check it

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code i used to create duplicate product:

```
$oldSku = $_GET['oldp'];
$newSku = $_GET['newp'];

if(!$oldSku || !$newSku){die('missing argument');}

$productFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');

$oldProduct = $productFactory->create()->loadByAttribute('sku',$oldSku);
$websiteIds = $oldProduct->getWebsiteIds();
$categoryIds = $oldProduct->getCategoryIds();

$duplicate = null;

$duplicate = $productFactory->create();
$duplicate->setData($oldProduct->getData());

$duplicate->setOptions([]);
$duplicate->setIsDuplicate(true);

$duplicate->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
$duplicate->setCreatedAt(null);
$duplicate->setUpdatedAt(null);
$duplicate->setId(null);
$duplicate->setStoreId(\Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID);
$duplicate->setVisibility(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);

$urlKey = $newSku;
$urlKey = preg_match('/(.*)-(\d+)$/', $urlKey, $matches) ? $matches[1] . '-' . ($matches[2] + 1) : $urlKey . '';
$duplicate->setUrlKey($urlKey);

$duplicate->setSku($newSku);
$duplicate->setName($newSku);

$duplicate->setData('meta_title',$newSku);
$duplicate->setData('meta_keyword','');
$duplicate->setData('meta_description','');

$duplicate->setWebsiteIds($websiteIds);
$duplicate->setCategoryIds($categoryIds);

$duplicate->setPrice(0);
$duplicate->setStockData(
            array(
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                'manage_stock' => 1,
                'is_in_stock' => 0,
                'qty' => 0
            )
    );

$duplicate->save();
```

Comment: I need also duplicate image set with image role. I have used  `$_product->addImageToMediaGallery($image_path, array( 'thumbnail','small_image','image' ), false, false);`  but Image Role not set on backend.

Comment: @nil108 Did you get any luck in duplicating the images?

Answer (score 1):

This is fast way to duplicate the product by id using object method :

```
//get object method
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

// load product by id
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

//duplicate product
$productCopier = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Copier')->copy($product);
```

Or by __construct :

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
 */
protected $product;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Copier
 */
protected $productCopier;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Copier $copier
) {        
    $this->product = $product;
    $this->productCopier = $copier; 
}
// load product by id
$product = $this->product->load($product_id);

//duplicate product
$productCopier = $this->productCopier->copy($product);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Duplicate` and then especially the Product Copier that is used (`\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Copier`).

It is used in the admin for duplicating products, but we used it in the past to programatically duplicate products with a new SKU and QTY. It might fit your needs.

Comment: I have used this and I am able to successfully duplicate the product, however, the duplicated product is missing images. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: When I am trying to duplicate I am facing  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\CopyConstructorInterface. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @DEEPJOSHI were u able to fix this issue? I am facing this.
I figure thus far, that di.xml for the Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Copier is defined in only Adminhtml